# I want to remove annotations , when the map scale is 50% or more. How can i do this?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to remove annotations , when the map scale is 50% or more. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Implement this method in your MKMapView's delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (map scale is > 50%) {
        [mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];
    }
}
```

Also, how are you calculating the zoom. What does 50% mean here?

Comment: What do you mean by map scale and what does 50% mean here? Is it when the user zooms in the map half way through?

Comment: 100% - this is a whole map on iphone screen (320, 480) , 50% - this is a whole map on iphone screen (640, 960)

Answer (score 0):

`MapKit` doesn't have the notion of zoom level. At any time, the map's viewport spans a particular `MKCoordinateRegion`, so a 50% zoom in or zoom out is simply half the previous region.

Answer (score 0):

Something I have found useful which makes it easier to manipulate the map view based on the notion of zoom levels, found [here](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/).